# Tracing Core Animation performance using instruments in Xcode 4.5 later

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, instruments

I had been going through a `iOS reference book`. Its basically on `iOS 5` and the author explained tracing the core animation performance using `Instruments`. 
[image]

Problem is I'm not finding the Graphics option in the Xcode version 4.5.2. Could somebody tell me if I can measure the graphics performance in some other way?

Comment: Are you profiling on the device or the simulator?

Comment: Simulator. Thank you, got that option on the device.

Comment: Ok, I've added that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Graphics profiling is only available (and, if you think about it) only makes sense on the device. Any frame rates you get on the simulator won't really mean anything in terms of device performance.